# postgresql convert bytea to integer type

Tags: postgresql, pickle, plpgsql

A PostgreSQL table has a column of type bytea. Some of integer and string values are inserted into this column.

Is there a way to fetch the original integer/string values back using psql?

```
bitnami_airflow=> select value from xcom where key='warehouse_ids_count'  limit 5;
       value
--------------------
 \x80034d926b2e
 \x80034a74e9dd002e
 \x80034dc6072e
 \x80034a6c1701002e
 \x80034d392d2e
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Can you also add a few insert statements? Also, never post images of code chucks, but the code chunks themselves as `text`.

Comment: Also, what is the encoding of the data? Hex 80 doesn't look like it is a digit in any encoding.

Comment: the output of `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING` of psql is `UTF8`.

Comment: Trying to read an airflow table [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/xcom.html), values inserted are simple int and string eg. 111, "error_found", "s3_location" etc.

Comment: @AmritJangid That looks like [pickled python objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). In theory you could reverse-engineer the format and re-implement unpickling in PL/SQL, but I would recommend to use Python instead.

Comment: True, Can access the desired result once disabled pickling. Airflow by default pickle all the values of xcom.
To disable, set AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=False
and change airflow.cfg for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow configuration has an option for pickling the XCom values(In airflow.cfg), by default it's enabled.

```
enable_xcom_pickling = True
```

Once disabled the pickling, values can be fetched as a normal string.